# Firebase dynamic links are null after new install, but work well when installed

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

The deep linking configuration works well for both iOS and Android when the app is installed. The configuration files seem okay for the domain https://friends.unblnd.com/dynamic.

But deep links are not recognised after an install.

So the listener works well, but getting the initial url when starting from the background isn't.

- **Logcat: Pixel 2, emulator**

// When *app is installed* we get the *expected behaviour*:

```
I/ReactNativeJS: 'FIREBASE LISTENING:', { utmParameters: 
       { utm_source: 'firebase',
         utm_medium: 'dynamic_link',
         utm_campaign: 'Online Cooking | UNBLND' },
      minimumAppVersion: null,
      url: 'https://unblnd.com/invite/group/eyJpdiI6IkNyMSsxTnJRWHJyQys3ZWZZd0R5Tnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRlFaQ2o3R0F0cnRpLzFvYzZ3WC9tQT09IiwibWFjIjoiOWFhZmIzZjk2MjM1MGQ5YTU5Y2M5YjBmOTIwNTdjODZkMzE3ZGY4ZTMyOTZmOTNhY2ZhZGM5NGNjNzc1NDEzYiJ9' }
```

// When the Firebase Dynamic Link (friends.unblnd.com/dynamic/aF8A) is clicked, and the *app needs to be installed*, after the install the *deep link is not found*:

```
I/ReactNativeJS: 'FIREBASE URL:', null
```

- **React Native: configuration**

Deeplinking is configured within React Navigation v5. A custom function for getting the initial url is added and the subscribe function, the following `const linking` is added as an attribute `<NavigationContainer linking={linking} ...>`

```
  const linking = {
    prefixes: [
      'https://friends.unblnd.com/dynamic/',
      ...
    ],
    config: deepLinksConf,
    // Custom function to get the URL which was used to open the app
    async getInitialURL() {
      // First, you may want to do the default deep link handling
      // Check if app was opened from a deep link
      const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();
      console.log('FOUND URL:', url);

      if (url != null) {
        return url;
      }

      // Next, you would need to get the initial URL from your third-party integration
      // It depends on the third-party SDK you use
      const link = await dynamicLinks().getInitialLink();
      for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        setTimeout(async function () {
          console.log('FIREBASE:', i, await dynamicLinks().getInitialLink());
        }, 500 * i);
      }
      console.log('FIREBASE URL:', url);

      return link.url;
    },
    // Custom function to subscribe to incoming links
    subscribe(listener) {
      // First, you may want to do the default deep link handling
      const onReceiveURL = ({url}) => {
        console.log(url);
        ... handle url
        listener(url);
      };

      // Listen to incoming links from deep linking
      Linking.addEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);

      const unsubscribeToDynamicLinks = dynamicLinks().onLink((link) => {
        console.log('FIREBASE LISTENING:', link);
        onReceiveURL(link);
      });

      return () => {
        // Clean up the event listeners
        unsubscribeToDynamicLinks();
        Linking.removeEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);
      };
    },
  };
```

**- Configuration: Firebase Dynamic Links**

Open the deep link in your Android App
[APP]

If your app is not installed, send the user to
Google Play page for your app

**- React Native: Info**

```
System:
    OS: macOS 11.5.2
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1068NG7 CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Memory: 43.73 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.17.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 6.14.15 - ~/htdocs/unblnd_app/node_modules/.bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.10.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 14.5, DriverKit 20.4, macOS 11.3, tvOS 14.5, watchOS 7.4
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 28, 29
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 29.0.3, 30.0.2
      System Images: android-29 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 4.2 AI-202.7660.26.42.7486908
    Xcode: 12.5.1/12E507 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_265 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
    react-native: 0.64.2 => 0.64.2 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
    @react-native-firebase/analytics: "^12.8.0",
    @react-native-firebase/app: "^12.8.0",
    @react-native-firebase/dynamic-links: "^12.8.0",
    @react-navigation/native: "^5.9.4",
    @react-navigation/stack: "^5.14.5",
```

**How to make it work as expected?**
Now, it has the same behaviour as internal url schemes... Maybe it is required to try Branch.io?

Answer (score 0):

We started using branch.io and it works well:
[npm package - react native branch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-branch)

Answer (score 0):

After looking up firebase documentation and other stackoverflow options, we created a piece of code that helped to resolve this issue.

**You need to add "FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains" parameter in info.plist file.**

Dynamical URL :
`https://yourapp.page.link/?link=https://yourapp.com/test=12345&isi=14602xxxxx&ibi=com.xxxx.yourapp`

The important parameter in info.plist file :

```
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
<array>
    <string>https://yourapp.com</string>
    <string>https://yourapp.com/link</string>
</array>
```

If you have a production critical app which has this issue, do not hesitate to ask me for inputs. Hit me up at https://khushalbhalsod.nl.